# How can I use vi to edit prompt line of a utility?

Tags: bash, shell, prompt, vi, readline

I wrote a utility in bash that uses `read -e` to provide a prompt for sql-like queries. Sometimes these are long, so I want to be able to open vi, edit the current line and upon exiting, replace the line with the contents in vim. I read lines with `read`. Something like:

```
query> select .... from .... very long... <ctrl-e>
```

now in vi

```
select .... from .... very long...
```

edit to

```
select ...
from ....
very long ...
```

exit vi

```
query> select ...
from ....
very long ... <enter>
```

query runs.

UPDATE: using 'set -o vi' before the 'read -e' seems to be the way for me, but currently when I click `<esc>v` the buffer that opens doesn't contain what is on the line but some other query, from my history (but not the one I typed before).

Comment: If you are using Oracle SqlPlus it is `DEFINE _EDITOR = vim` but I guess you have to add in your question which database system you are using.

Comment: Is this from a shell script, as implied from your tags?  And using Bash's built-in `read` command?

Comment: "a utility that accepts sql-like queries" -- What utility? Ambiguity is bad. As you can see, both the current answers are about bash, not your "utility".

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [dbext plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356).

Answer (score 13):

First you have to make sure to use vi as shell command line editor:

```
set -o vi
```

Now you can type/copy your command to the command line. To leave insert mode and enter normal mode, use `Esc` or `Shift`+`Tab`. Now you can open `vi` by pressing `v`.

In `vi`, you can now do all the changes you want, save the buffer and exit `vi`, and the command gets executed.

Comment: That works in many shells, but does it work in a program that uses GNU Readline?  I tested with `psql` and also other interactive programs. It doesn't work, even if I wrap it with `rlwrap`.

Comment: It's not clear to me if the OP is doing this in the shell or at a prompt of an external utility.

Comment: I'm  doing this in  a utility that i wrote

Comment: tried this. when i type 'v' it indeed goes to vi, but not with the line I'm currently editing

Answer (score 9):

In bash, you can invoke an editor for the current command line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

On the system I have to hand, this isn't in the docs under `man readline` itself, but is in `man bash` under the "readline" section, so I'm not sure if it's a bash-specific feature, or if other readline-based programs would support it.

Here is the documentation from bash:

> #### `edit-and-execute-command` (`C-xC-e`)
>
> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands.  Bash attempts to invoke `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, and `emacs` as the editor, in that order.

Comment: Just a note - to make the `read` builtin use the interactive `readline` settings (including the `edit-and-execute-command` binding), you need to invoke it as `read -e`.  BTW, I have confirmed that this works.

Comment: Is there a way to : edit in $VISUAL, and return to prompt but not execute straight away?

Comment: @OlivierDulac I don't know of a "clever" way, but a simple way is to put a `#` at the beginning of the command to make the whole thing a comment. Then when it's "executed", it won't do anything, but will be in the history, so you can press up and edit it again.

Comment: @IMSoP: I .... I am ashamed I didn't think of that ^^ thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As long as your prompt is a shell prompt (e.g. a call to `read`) all the other answers are valid and useful

If it isn't (you are not completely clear in this respect), e.g. when you are using a SQL interpreter `xxxsql` you can use 
`rlwrap --multi-line -a xxxsql` and then use a special (configurable) key to invoke the editor of your choice (specified by e.g.  `export RLWRAP_EDITOR="vim '+call cursor(%L,%C)"` on the input -- the `call_cursor` is useful to preserve the cursor position when invoking `vim`)

As an extra perk, you will have full command history even for the multi-line commands (which are "compressed" into single-line ones before they are put on the history list, but expanded again when they are re-used)

edit: more information can be found on  [rlwraps Github page](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap). Like all commands that use the [GNU readline library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) most of its behaviour is [specified](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/inputrc.html)  in the users `$INPUTRC`  to which `rlwrap` has added a number of its own options that control, among other things, the above-mentioned special key to invoke an external editor (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> by default)

Comment: This seems like a good approach, but the instructions seem incomplete: what is the "special key" by default, and where do you configure it? And is `rlwrap` part of a separate package I need to install? It isn't present on the couple of Linux boxen I have in front of me.

Comment: I extended my answer a bit to make it more complete. `rlwrap` is not Linux-specific, but it can be found in most distributions (not usually installed by default).

Comment: I agree with IMSop, this seems like the best approach.  But it is missing the fact that `rlwrap` can be used entirely in vi mode.  If you add `set editing-mode vi` inside `~/.inputrc` then `rlwrap` will respect that and your `rlwrap xxxsql` (e.g. `rlwrap sqlite3`) will use vi mode.  There is no need for `RLWRAP_EDITOR` hacks.

Comment: Utilities such as `psql` for postgres, and `mysql` for mysql, have native support for readline, which will work a lot better than trying to use `rlwrap`. `sqlplus` unfortunately does not.

Comment: @grochmal: The question was about multi-line editing. Even readline-aware commands may need `rlwrap` for that (and then, `set editing-mode vi` will not determine the editor used for multi-line edits)

Comment: @HansLub - Yeah, that's a valid point (+1).  And I learned something about `:h cursor` checking how the wrap will work.  Good stuff.